# Nuxt - How to set public path at runtime rather than at build time

Tags: docker, vue.js, nuxt.js

My web application is deployed to staging and production environments using Docker. This means `npm run build` runs at docker build time.

I want to put application version in front of the static stuff that live on `/_nuxt/*application version*` and that's a different publicPath for each version.

Now because application version has been assigned after the docker build, not getting right version in publicPath

Is there any way to tell nuxt to resolve the publicPath at runtime rather than at build time?

build: {
    publicPath: `/_nuxt/${APP_VERSION}`,
  },

Comment: AFAIK the public path is used by nuxt to include static assets in your code so I don't think it's possible

Comment: You cant. PublicPath is a build time.

Comment: can you provide your `dockerfile`